# Поиск на сайте при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

https://jut.su/anime/ нужно запарсить каждую страницу после ввода названия аниме, не имею соображения как это сделать, как передать в строку ввода название ?

Answer (score 1):

На странице сайта есть 2 элемента поиска:

- Большой, с кнопкой <kbd>Найти</kbd>, оно вызывает `POST` запрос на `/search/`, который возвращает ответ с редиректом на конкретную страницу аниме
- Ниже, `Быстрый поиск ...`, который `POST` запрос на `/anime/` и возвращает список аниме, работает как фильтр

#### Я сделал пример для второго.

Описание:

- Используем [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) для отправки запроса на сайт:

  - Создаем сессию через `requests.session()`, чтобы иметь общие заголовки запросов и помнить куки, что сайт может возвращать для последующей отправки
  - Добавляем заголовок `User-Agent`, чтобы притвориться браузером
  - Отправляем POST запрос с данными формы через метод `post`. Данные заполняются через словарь в `data`. Данные для отправки посмотрел через браузер, используя инструмент инспектор, на вкладке Сети. Добавляем заголовок `X-Requested-With`, чтобы притвориться `AJAX`
- Используем [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) для парсинга

  - Для поиска использую css-селекторы, для них нужно использовать методы `select` и `select_one`
  - Ссылки на аниме относительные, а чтобы сделать их абсолютными использую функцию [urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin)
- Для стандартизации сбора данных создаем класс и [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) для автоматического создания конструктора, описания класса и т.п.

*Думаю, на сайте результаты поиска могут разделены на страницы и подгружаться по мере пролистывания, эту логику не реализовывал*

Зависимости:

- `pip install requests`
- `pip install bs4`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a08d144aa74be63c9e91d550abecddba2c656b6b/html_parsing/jut_su/anime__search.py)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from typing import List

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


@dataclass
class Anime:
    url: str
    title: str


session = requests.session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0'


def search(text: str) -> List[Anime]:
    data = {
        'ajax_load': 'yes',
        'start_from_page': 1,
        'show_search': text,
        'anime_of_user': '',
    }
    headers = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',  # AJAX
    }
    rs = session.post('https://jut.su/anime/', headers=headers, data=data)
    rs.raise_for_status()

    items = []
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.text, 'html.parser')
    for anime_el in root.select('.all_anime_global'):
        url = urljoin(rs.url, anime_el.a['href'])
        title = anime_el.select_one('.aaname').text

        items.append(Anime(url, title))

    return items
```

Проверяем:

```
for anime in search(text='гора'):
    print(anime)
```

Результат:

```
Anime(url='https://jut.su/shiki/', title='Усопшие')
Anime(url='https://jut.su/slime-taoshite-300-nen/', title='Убивала слизней 300 лет до максимального уровня')
Anime(url='https://jut.su/reikenzan/', title='Гора Священного меча')
Anime(url='https://jut.su/shakunetsu-kabaddi/', title='Пылающий Кабадди')
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте, вместо того чтобы искать аниме в поисковой строке, спарсить ссылки и названия на аниме со всех страниц и сохранить их куда-нибудь, а уже после доставать ссылки и парсить нужные данные.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = 0
anime_list = dict()

while True:
    page += 1
    url = f'https://jut.su/anime/page-{page}'

    req = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    all_anime_info = soup.find_all(class_='all_anime_global')

    if not all_anime_info:
        break

    print(page, '/ 28')

    for anime_info in all_anime_info:
        anime_name = anime_info.find(class_='aaname').text
        anime_link = 'https://jut.su' + anime_info.find('a').get('href')
        anime_list[anime_name] = anime_link

print(anime_list)
```

Но если вам хочется именно через поисковою строку, то лучше использовать Селениум.

Comment: Можно немного упростить код, если использовать css-селекторы: `all_anime_info = soup.select('.all_anime_content .all_anime_global')`. Для получения из относительных ссылок абсолютных как тут `anime_link = 'https://jut.su/anime/' + anime_info.find('a').get('href')` лучше использовать `urljoin` из `from urllib.parse import urljoin` :)

Comment: Насчет поиска по названию, тут необязательно селениум, нужно в инспекторе браузера посмотреть какой запрос отправляет сайт и повторить его :) Скорее всего, там будет ajax-запрос

Comment: Кст, пробовали работать через сессии в `requests`? Они удобны тем, что запоминают куки, что приходят от сайтов и отправляют их в запросах, плюс если сессии указывать заголовки, то они будут включены автоматически, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2129e9f55ea69a2f8e2c831100640aa8bd86b20c/html_parsing/rpcs3_net__compatibility.py#L16

Comment: а можно поподробнее как селекторы упрощают код. Просто между строками  `all_anime_info = soup.select('.all_anime_content .all_anime_global')` и `all_anime_info = soup.find_all(class_='all_anime_global')` не кажется будто есть сильная разница. А с библиотекой urllib я не сталкивался, поэтому сказать ничего не могу.

Comment: сессии и правда использовать удобно, но их наличие не обязательно, я и не использую. Хотя с ними было бы и в правду лучше.

Comment: `.all_anime_content .all_anime_global` это поиск элементов с классом `all_anime_global`, которые есть в элементах с классом `all_anime_content`. У вас в `all_anime_info = soup.find_all(class_='all_anime_global')` нет уточнения о родительских элементах, кст. это тоже самое что `all_anime_info = soup.select('.all_anime_global')` :) Точка в css-селекторе это указание класса. Кст, если нужно указать, непосредственных детей, то используется символ `>`: `.all_anime_content > .all_anime_global`, тогда вернутся `all_anime_global`, что являются прямыми детьми `all_anime_content `

Comment: А еще, `lxml` хороший парсер, быстрый, но не из коробки. Его можно заменить на `html.parser`

Comment: На счёт ajax запросов у меня мало опыта в парсинге, поэтому сколько я не копаюсь не могу найти нужные данные. А за советы спасибо. Вот только у меня вопрос нужно ли вносить правки в ответ или лучше оставить как есть?

Comment: ajax это тот же запрос http, разница имеет для браузеров, для них эти запросы происходят асинхронно. Не этот ответ, думаю, нормальный. Но я бы попробовал разобраться с поиском на том сайте и сделал отдельным ответом (я бы и сам посмотрел на поиск того сайта, но после работы :))

Comment: Кст, насчет urljoin, у вас ссылка на аниме неправильно формируется, посмотрите как у вас формируется и на какую ссылку у сайта :)

Comment: Накидал в ответе пример с запросом поиска :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! после вашего примера всё встало на свои места. ошибку в формировании запроса нашёл и исправил. Очень вам благодарен за уделённое время!