# Как сформировать запрос через поисковую строку сайта?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Начал недавно заниматься парсингом и решил распарсить сайт https://jut.su/anime. хотел сделать так, чтобы вводилось с клавиатуры название аниме, и тебе выдавались его жанры, описание и т.д. но столкнулся с проблемой, что не получается работать с поисковой строкой, а доставать всё подряд не хочется. Я увидел, что на сайте есть строка быстрого поиска с именем anime_fast_search, и через пост запрос передаю туда название. Но ничего не изменяется, и на выходе получаю просто все названия, которые есть на странице. Заранее спасибо.

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://jut.su/anime/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'
}

params = {
    'anime_fast_search': 'Ванпанчмен'
}

req = requests.post(url, headers = headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

names = soup.find_all(class_="aaname")
for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: Нет такого параметра в запросе. И там не все так просто как вам кажется. Мой вам совет используйте селениум.

Comment: Ответ подсказали здесь:[Поиск-на-сайте-при-парсинге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1385799/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5/1387381?noredirect=1#comment2466176_1387381)